# Is there a way to deny scheduled Timer event?

Tags: python, multithreading

Consider this. I want to deny execution of Timer event:

```
import threading


def say_hello():
    print 'hello'

threading.Timer(10, say_hello, ()).start()
# now for some reason my plans have changed
# is there a way to erase that Timer and deny execution of say_hello?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = threading.Timer(10, say_hello, ())
t.start()  # start timer
t.cancel()  # stop it
```